# Creating Multiple Charts based on dictionary length using javascript

Tags: javascript, dictionary, flask, charts, canvasjs

I am new to javascript and trying to plot multiple graphs of the length of the dictionary in javascript using **Canvasjs** and **flask**. I have a dictionary with a list of tuples passing from flask to my template here is my dictionary.

```
{'923114566780479 (1).xlsx': [('181112949', 1), ('156860', 1), ('3007322293014', 3), ('3007789510214', 2)], 'Copy of 9231645678120167 (1).xlsx': [(383362396260316, 1), ('0310566103033882', 13), ('0315311456791689', 1), ('0315826247894310', 1)]}
```

In this dictionary, I have two keys because I have uploaded two files and I want two charts now if the user uploaded 5 or 6 then I want 5 or 6 graphs.

here is the code that I have tried

```
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
                     <script>

{%for key in first%}
var myvar = '{{key}}';
console.log(myvar);
{%endfor%}
                  </script>
                      <script>

  window.onload = function () {
{% for key in first %}
$('#piechart').append('<div id="draw_chart'+myvar+'"></div>');
chart = new CanvasJS.Chart(myvar, {
    animationEnabled: true,
     exportEnabled: false,
  theme: "light1", // "light1", "light2", "dark1", "dark2"
   backgroundColor: "transparent",
    data: [{
        type: "doughnut",
        startAngle: 20,
        //innerRadius: 10,
        indexLabelFontSize: 17,
        indexLabelFontColor: "black",
        indexLabel: "#percent%",
        toolTipContent: "<b>{label}:</b> {y}",
        dataPoints: [

        {%for b in first[key]%}
        { y: {{[b][0][1]}}, label: "{{[b][0][0]}}" },
            {%endfor%}
            ]
    }]
});

var container = document.getElementById('draw_chart'+myvar).appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
chart.render();

{%endfor%}
}

                        </script>

<body>

  <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="card-body" id="piechart" style="min-height: 250px; height: 250px; max-height: 250px; max-width: 90%;">
                    </div>
                </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

chart container that you are passing to create chart is not proper. Also, `myvar` will point to key of last element in your dictionary. So, id of the container should be  `id="draw_chart'+'{{key}}'+'"` and you should pass same value while creating chart like `new CanvasJS.Chart("draw_chart'+'{{key}}', {})`.

Please take a look at this code snippet for sample code.

```
window.onload = function() {
  var charts = []; { %
    for key in first %
  }
  $('#piechart').append('<div id="draw_chart' + '{{key}}' + '" style="height: 300px;width: 100%;"></div>');
  charts.push(new CanvasJS.Chart("draw_chart" + '{{key}}', {
    animationEnabled: true,
    exportEnabled: false,
    theme: "light1", // "light1", "light2", "dark1", "dark2"
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    data: [{
      type: "doughnut",
      startAngle: 20,
      //innerRadius: 10,
      indexLabelFontSize: 17,
      indexLabelFontColor: "black",
      indexLabel: "#percent%",
      toolTipContent: "<b>{label}:</b> {y}",
      dataPoints: [

        { %
          for b in first[key] %
        } {
          y: {
            {
              [b][0][1]
            }
          },
          label: "{{[b][0][0]}}"
        },
        { % endfor %
        }
      ]
    }]
  })); { % endfor %
  }
  charts.forEach(chart => chart.render())
}
```